# Clone one span into another for each group of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many sets of div and I'm trying to copy the content of a specific span into another one and repeat the same operation for all my divs.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <span class="ContentGoesHere"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="DivWithContent">
        <span class="ContentComesFromHere">This is my content 1</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <span class="ContentGoesHere"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="DivWithContent">
        <span class="ContentComesFromHere">This is my content 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <span class="ContentGoesHere"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="DivWithContent">
        <span class="ContentComesFromHere">This is my content 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery code is:

```
$("div.item").each(function(i) {

    $(this).find('span.ContentComesFromHere').clone(true, true).contents().appendTo('span.ContentGoesHere');

});
```

It almost works, right now what I get in my span.ContentGoesHere is: This is my content 1This is my content 2This is my content 3  - and it's the same content for all but the content needs to be specific to each div.item.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Class names should be unique to perform the unique clones. Try involving the index 'i' in the class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try The code below

```
$("div.item").each(function(i) {
   $(this).find('span.ContentComesFromHere')
   .clone(true,true).contents()
   .appendTo($(this).find('span.ContentGoesHere'));
});
```

To See The demo in jsFiddle

[Click here to see Demo In JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/975v3d1j/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code bellow.

```
$("div.item").each(function(i) {
    var content = $(this).find('span.ContentComesFromHere').html();
    $(this).find('span.ContentGoesHere').html(content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type your function like this:

```
$("div.item").each(function(i) {
    let content = $(this).find('span.ContentComesFromHere');
    let contentTarget = $(this).find('span.ContentGoesHere');
    content.clone().appendTo(contentTarget);
});
```

Then the end result will looks like this:

```
This is my content 1
This is my content 1
This is my content 2
This is my content 2
This is my content 3
This is my content 3
```

See snippet for the working code.

```js
$("div.item").each(function(i) {
    let content = $(this).find('span.ContentComesFromHere');
    let contentTarget = $(this).find('span.ContentGoesHere');
    content.clone().appendTo(contentTarget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <span class="ContentGoesHere"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="DivWithContent">
        <span class="ContentComesFromHere">This is my content 1</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <span class="ContentGoesHere"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="DivWithContent">
        <span class="ContentComesFromHere">This is my content 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <span class="ContentGoesHere"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="DivWithContent">
        <span class="ContentComesFromHere">This is my content 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**See it working**](https://plnkr.co/edit/4W075hN5mML9EyWq1Nm9?p=preview)

Your way

```
       $("div.item").each(function(i) {             
         var targetElement = $(this).find('span.ContentGoesHere');
         var sourceHtml = $(this).find('span.ContentComesFromHere').clone().contents()
          sourceHtml.appendTo(targetElement);
      });
```

Simpler way

```
       $("div.item").each(function(i) {
         var contents = $(this).find('span.ContentComesFromHere').html();    
         $(this).find('span.ContentGoesHere').html(contents);
      });
```

In your case you need find the source and target both by $(this).find()

Answer (score 0):

Just replace to **.appendTo($(this).find('span.ContentGoesHere'));** into your **JS** code and I hope it will be work.